# jQuery Input Mask not working in my Rails 4 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's my application.haml 
[image]

The field that I'm trying to mask (which is the :contact_number field):
[image]

This is what I get when I inspect that field: 
[image]

I think the reason I'm not getting it right is because I have two .js files - an application.js and a posts.js file. The field I'm trying to mask is a new form for a new post.

I've tried this code in my application.js file:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$("#post_contact_number").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

I've tried putting it in the posts.js.coffee file:

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $("#post_contact_number").mask "99/99/9999"
```

I'm following this guide http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ and running Rails 4. I'm not sure what's wrong.